# Comparing meta-data (the history) of a VSS repository with those ones of a SVN repository

Tags: svn, migration, repository, metadata, visual-sourcesafe

Good morning to every body.

My task is to "migrate" a huge VSS repository into a SVN one. I have used Polarion SVN Importer for a test migration on a small repository, and it has been satisfactory.
The problem is that I should check if all the meta-data (the number of revisions and commits, the authors, the date and the comments of each commit/change) have been correctly transferred. The VSS history file and the SVN log file are too long to be analyzed by a reading guy. So I suppose I should create or use a software to compare them or, anyway, to find a way to compare metadata of the two repositories.
Another problem is that not all the comments I have used in the VSS repository are present in its history, so I can not completely trust the history file, neither the log file. I may compare the file in the DB of the two repositories, but all the file are codified and I don't know how to decode the information from them.

Any suggestion?